# Values initialized and set outside interrupt are zero within interrupt C++ on Xilinx Zynq

Tags: c++, xilinx, zynq

I am experiencing a rather odd issue with my code where I have a value that I initialize in the main. Once I try to call that variable inside an interrupt it is 0. What am I missing here? Do different variables live within an interrupt?

I would like to note that this is a more theoretical question about interrupts and whether I can not share values between idle and interrupts.

```
Supervisor supervisor;
XScuTimer TimerInstance;
XScuGic IntcInstance;
uint32_t offset;

void interruptRoutine(void *CallBackRef) {

    // Define pointer to timer
    XScuTimer *TimerInstancePtr = (XScuTimer *) CallBackRef;

    // If timer is expired, clear interrupt status
    if (XScuTimer_IsExpired(TimerInstancePtr)) {
        XScuTimer_ClearInterruptStatus(TimerInstancePtr);

        // Why is offset 0 within the interrupt routine?
        xil_printf("Interrupt: %u\n", offset);

    }

}

//.. I omitted the interrupt init method ..//

int main() {

    while (true) {
        // Get all sensor data
        offset = 1;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowledge of the other classes mentioned in the code

Comment: @EdHeal assume that the classes are fine and that the value of `offset` is known and correct within the while loop.

Comment: Is it reentrant - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29

Comment: Have you tried to add `volatile` to the parameter? Shouldn't make a difference in your case, but I'd recommend adding to must things regarding change in an interrupt.

Comment: @pingul yes I have, didn't change anything

Comment: Missing `volatile`.  Also check the assembly listing in case code has been optimized out.  `%u` converts an `unsigned int`, is that the same size as  `uint32_t`?

Comment: @RichardCritten even with a regular int it's the same issue. I'm looking into the assembly

Comment: does xil_printf support %u? is %u a unsigned 32 bit int?

Comment: You'll definitely need to declare variables as volatile if you want to examine their values inside the while loop, but I would not expect that to be needed in your case. Have you verified that main has reached the while loop?